# object has been rewritten In loop

Tags: groovy

I have code like this:

```
def updateSensor(List<String> boardIds, SensorShort sensor) {
    for (String boardId : boardIds) {
        println("Working on ${boardId} for ${sensor.sensorId}")
        pool.submit({
            println("[${Thread.currentThread().name}] Working on ${boardId} for ${sensor.sensorId}")

        })
    }
}
```

result of this code is:

```
Working on 400 for 11
Working on 100 for 11
Working on 101 for 11
Working on 300 for 11

[pool-4-thread-4] Working on 300 for 11
[pool-4-thread-1] Working on 300 for 11
[pool-4-thread-3] Working on 300 for 11
[pool-3-thread-1] Working on 300 for 11
```

but is wrong. It seams boardId object has been rewritten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're submitting a job based on a non-final local variable, instead try:

```
def updateSensor(List<String> boardIds, SensorShort sensor) {
    boardIds.each { String boardId ->
        println("Working on ${boardId} for ${sensor.sensorId}")
        pool.submit {
            println("[${Thread.currentThread().name}] Working on ${boardId} for ${sensor.sensorId}")
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with the original code is that by the time the Closure is evaluated on a separate thread, the loop has finished, and the local `boardId` variable has the value of the last item in the list.  So each job runs with the last element, rather than the element you required.

In Java, you would declare (indeed, Java would force you to declare the variable as `final`):

```
for( final String boardId : boardIds ) {
```

However, groovy does not have local final variables :-/

By doing it with `boardIds.each`, the local `boardId` variable inside the `each` closure has the value you need...

Hope that explains it?

Comment: thanks, but I am not sure I understand what was wrong with original code. Could you explain or give some links?

Comment: @yaroslavTir Added a bit more explanation...  Hope it helps!  If not, let me know and I'll have another go at explaining it :-)